# Elements stacking rather then lining up with inline-block

Tags: html, css, mobile

**Objective**
To have the buttons line up horizontally when on screens between 480 and 767px. Like this.
[image: objective]

**Background**
They line up properly most of the time (as shown in above screenshot) but on iPhone when you rotate from portrait to mobile, sometimes the buttons stack. Also when you resize the browser window from smaller than 480 to larger.

[image]

I wanted them to each take up half of the screen. But I was having problems because of padding. So I solved by making the buttons `width: 46%`.

**Current State**
I have the navigation on this test site at http://bruxzir.jgallardo.me/

Here is the code related to the buttons

**meta**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-buttons">
  <a href="/dentist/authorized-bruxzir-labs/" class="main-button">
    <span class="button-highlight">Find an</span>
    <br>Authorized Lab
  </a>

  <a href="/lab/become-authorized-bruxzir-lab.aspx" class="main-button become">
    <span class="button-highlight">Become an</span>
    <br>Authorized Lab
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-buttons {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px 10px 0 0;
}

.main-buttons a {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-left: 10px #BA222B solid;
  color: #fff;
  display:block;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 270px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .main-buttons {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .main-buttons a {
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .main-buttons {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .main-buttons a {
    border: none;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
    width: 47%;
  }

  .become {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the problem pretty well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this modified JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nErn6/

Here are the relevant CSS changes:

```
.main-buttons a {
    ...
    display: block;
    ...
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: 4%;
}
.main-buttons a:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

- Replaced `display: inline-block` with `display: block`
- Used `float: left` to handle horizontal positioning
- Used `box-sizing: border-box` to account for padding
- Used percentage-based margin and sizing

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly. Thank you for your very detailed but concise explanation.

Answer (score 2):

For `.main-buttons a` set it to `float : right;`.

I believe that should do the trick for you.

The reason that they stack is because of the margins and padding that you have.

If you want the buttons to take up half of the screen, instead of trying to figure out certain margins and padding just set the width of the container to `50%` and then you can mess around with the padding and positioning.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .main-buttons a {
    border: none;
    float: left; /* remove display: inline-block; */
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
    width: 47%;
  }
  .main-buttons a.become {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

that should fix your issue and i think it happens cuz inline block gives spaces. You can read about it [here](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).